# Blender 2.82 hardops

Tags: animation, 3d, blender

Geeting an error while using mirror in hardops. I am using mac and it is working fine in windows. can it not be used in Mac?

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/***/***/Library/Application Support/Blender/2.82/scripts/addons/HOps/operators/Gizmos/mirror.py", line 347, in invoke
    current_tool = ToolSelectPanelHelper._tool_get_active(context, 'VIEW_3D', None)[0][0]
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.82/scripts/startup/bl_ui/space_toolsystem_common.py", line 250, in _tool_get_active
    for item in ToolSelectPanelHelper._tools_flatten(cls.tools_from_context(context, mode)):
AttributeError: type object 'ToolSelectPanelHelper' has no attribute 'tools_from_context'

location: :-1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can help: I had this error on windows with previous currium Hard Ops, which is solved with latest Hard Ops update : Neodymium
[Link to Hard Ops on BlenderMarket](https://blendermarket.com/products/hardopsofficial)